# Understanding AWS SDK Java 2.x (Async vs Sync) HTTP Clients

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, multithreading, http, aws-sdk

The AWS Java 2.x SDK offers many different http client alternatives. Two of which are the:

1. Apache-based **sync** HTTP client
2. AWS CRT-based **async** HTTP client

To help me understand the difference between the Sync and Async, I was trying to understand the differences described in the AWS documentation [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration.html).

For example, when browsing their recommendations as to which to use, I found the following very peculiar:

> The Apache-based sync HTTP client is recommended for "low latency over
> high throughput", while the AWS CRT-based async HTTP client is
> recommended for "high throughput over low latency".

In short, how on earth could the Apache-based sync HTTP client have a lower latency than one of the Async HTTP clients? I would expect the latency to be based on network latency and for that it's completely irrelevant what client (whether sync or async) you use.

Also, how could an Async client have a higher throughput than a sync HTTP client, that also doesn't make sense to me? I would expect the opposite because the sync client will busy wait until the response is available, while the async will go run off do something else in the meantime, and therefore might not be ready to handle the response when it arrives.

Below is more of the thinking to the above.

My understanding is that high throughput and low latency are inversely correlated. If you increase one, you generally decrease the other, and vice-versa. Of course, there could be other factors that could, for example, decrease throughput while holding latency steady. Nonetheless, I don't see how either clients would effect network throughput or latency.

It's a bit confusing to me what the difference would be in running the Apache-based sync HTTP client wrapped in a promise vs. directly using one of the async HTTP client (for example either the netty or CRT-based async clients) - I believe I understand the differences, but let me state below.

They both use thread pools (at least, for sync if you're using the Apache-based sync client), they both have to wait for responses.

I would guess that when using the Apache-based sync HTTP client to create an HTTP client request, it typically draws a thread from the thread pool, uses that thread to create an HTTP connection, initiates the request, then busy waits for the response that will continually consume CPU time for the thread to continue to poll to see if the response is available.

Meanwhile, with the async HTTP client, it follows the same procedure as above, except it doesn't busy wait for a response, it will use that thread for some other purpose in the meantime, or if no other purpose is found it will sleep without consuming CPU time until the response comes in; the response will via some sort of OS mechanism trigger the JVM to wake up that slept thread to handle the response.

As per my understanding, I don't see how the Apache-based sync HTTP client could have a lower latency than the AWS CRT-based async HTTP client? I don't see how the AWS CRT-based async HTTP client could have a higher throughput? It would seem to me like the difference between the two mostly just determine the efficiency at which the program uses the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS CRT-based HTTP client is only available for S3, and it uses multipart upload API and byte-range fetches. That's why it can handle higher throughput. The overhead of using these mechanisms results in a higher latency.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/crt-based-s3-client.html

> The AWS CRT-based S3 client—built on top of the AWS Common Runtime (CRT)—is an alternative S3 asynchronous client. It transfers objects to and from Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) with enhanced performance and reliability by automatically using Amazon S3's multipart upload API and byte-range fetches.
>
> The AWS CRT-based S3 client improves transfer reliability in case there is a network failure. Reliability is improved by retrying individual failed parts of a file transfer without restarting the transfer from the beginning.
>
> In addition, the AWS CRT-based S3 client offers enhanced connection pooling and Domain Name System (DNS) load balancing, which also improves throughput.
>
> You can use the AWS CRT-based S3 client in place of the SDK's standard S3 asynchronous client and take advantage of its improved throughput right away.

Netty-based HTTP client and AWS CRT-based HTTP client uses nonblocking I/O which allows you to have a few threads what handle many concurrent requests in comparison to Apache-based sync HTTP client where you need to have as many threads as concurrent requests.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html

> The AWS SDK for Java 2.x features truly nonblocking asynchronous clients that implement high concurrency across a few threads. The AWS SDK for Java 1.x has asynchronous clients that are wrappers around a thread pool and blocking synchronous clients that don’t provide the full benefit of nonblocking I/O.

Comment: Yes, you're logic involving the use of `multipart upload` and `byte-range` would seem to definitely explain the differences claimed between higher throughput and higher latency, in their documentation. But I find the documentation to still be lacking and confusing, because `multipart upload` is conventionally only used when the upload is [at least 100 mb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html), so in these cases, are there still differences in throughput/latency? Who knows. Most requests are less than 100 mb, so I would think this to be important.

Comment: @Nick 100MB is just recommended size, you can configure the minimum part size. The smaller part size, the more requests, the higher latency

Comment: Yes, @abler98, I understand that, but I would reckon AWS CRT-based async client doesn't use below their own recommendations, so my comment is not any less relevant. And even if they did, it would seem foolish to use `multipart upload` for small files. So I still don't believe their description in their documentation is clear - if they're going to claim that AWS CRT-based async client has a higher thoughput/lower latency, they should clarify that that's only for very large files. It's already a confusing and difficult topic (being concurrency and all) so clarity is important I would think.

Comment: And you know, the `multipart upload` feature actually has nothing to do with the async client. The `multipart upload` feature can exist on both the so-called "sync" client or the "async" client. So then it's really just flat out wrong to explain the differences in the async client vs the sync clients in terms of throughput or latency if the reasons are somehow due to `multipart upload`.

Comment: @Nick it is possible to use multipart upload in any of the clients, but the CRT-based client does this by default, and there is also the ability to set a target throughput.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-crt-based-s3-client-and-the-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/

Comment: That's good information, nice to know, but for the topic of conversation I personally would not deem it relevant, but I'm not really complaining, I'm happy to have discovered the meaning of the referred aws documentation - as I do believe you.